# What qualifies as a "relation" in a knowledge base?

Tags: relation, knowledge-graph

So, this may be a question that stems from my lack of knowledge, but what would quality as a "relation" in a knowledge base?

For example, if we had the sentence:

> My dad likes to eat sandwiches. My dad also has a brother.

In this (rather random) example sentence, I can tell that one knowledge base triple example could be `(My dad, likes, to eat sandwiches)`.

Would the example of `(My dad, has, a brother)` also work?